# java 8 Instant.now() is showing wrong instant time

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

In Java 8 `Instant.now()` method showing wrong time  .
My code looks like :

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
public class DateTimeDemo{
    public static void main(String []args){
            Instant now = Instant.now();
            System.out.println(now);
        }

    }
```

Its date part is correct but time part .

eg

> 2016-07-11T11:01:25.498Z
>   but in my system it is 4.31 PM

**I am using Asia/Calcutta TimeZone**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's the correct time. Note the "Z" at the end, indicating [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) - 11:01:25 in UTC is 16:31:25 in Asia/Calcutta.

If you want to represent "now" in your default time zone, use [`ZonedDateTime.now()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--) instead.

Comment: The `Z` is short for `Zulu` which means [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't think "z" is short for "zulu". From that page "z" is used because UTC is the "zero" timezone and "zulu" is just the NATO phonetic alphabet word for "z".

Comment: @mowwwalker Same difference to me. I prefer the brevity. Furthermore, the modern [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard used by industry does not recognize the [military/aviation zones A-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones), so the distinction is not relevant to most of us.